# link internet router to PCs using RJ-45 port

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, lan

I have TB-link internet router and `LAN cable` linked to `RJ-45 port`

now when I need to connect a PC to that `LAN port` using another `LAN cable` linked from that `LAN cable` to a PC it wont connect and the network ICON show Read **X** sign

I tried to user `crossover cable` but it also wont connect

I tried to use an  junction adapter as below

a `LAN cable` from `RJ-45 port` to the junction adapter then
another cable from junction adapter to the PCs after doing that the PC is connected and everything works fine but I got a problem each time the router is switched off/on the connection is disconnected and I have to 
dis-attach the junction adapter and re-link the junction adapter with opposite side to restore the connection

I am really beginner in networks and I want to know what I have do wrong please
which issue is the correct one

[image: image for junction adapter I use]

thanks

Comment: It seems to me as a bad connector issue.

Comment: Hello, I cannot understand your second paragraph. Perhaps a scheme would come in handy here. Which LAN port and cable are you referring to when you're using `that` in front?

Comment: Check that "Auto MDI/MDIX" is enabled on both router port and NIC port. Make sure the cables have standard wires.

Comment: Can you show the pinout on both ends of these cables? and is the coupler an inline coupler or a crossover coupler?

Comment: @montonero i tried to use 3 adapters

Comment: @Akina more details please where i can find them ?

Comment: @MaQleod its inline coupler

Comment: *where i can find them ?* Look router Port settings and NIC properties - Additional parameters.

Comment: @Sam I'm not talking about adapter but about some issue with cables/sockets of router/NIC since you have the issue with a direct connection. It would be also nice to try this router with some other NIC and vice versa.